# C# MongoDb Driver not GeoJSON compatible?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, leaflet, geojson

I am building a web app using Leaflet.js, ASP.Net Core webapi service layer and MongoDB to persist data.

It seems that the C# driver for MongoDb does not serialise or deserialise the GeoJSON objects correctly.

Ideally I would be able to post the GeoJSON objects directly from leaflet to the webapi controller which should simply pass this object into my repository for persistance in MongoDb.  However it produces null (which is the standard behaviour for a class mis-match - from the webapi `[FromBody]` model binding - as it does not throw exceptions).

So to test what it is expecting (what the C# MongoDb driver objects serialise as) I have created a service that returns a GeoJSON object directly and it returns the following - which I do not believe is valid GeoJSON:

```
"location":{ 
    "coordinates":{ 
      "values":[-121.97620341421, 37.503287248864], 
      "longitude":-121.97620341421, 
      "latitude":37.503287248864 },
    "type":7, 
    "boundingBox":null, 
    "coordinateReferenceSystem":null, 
    "extraMembers":null },
```

AFAIK the type property should be "Point" and the coordinates property should only contain the array of long/lat values - not an object with 3 properties!

My C# property looks like this:

```
public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> location { get; set; }
```

The object being sent from my leaflet front end looks like this:

```
"location": {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
      -105.01621,
      39.57422
  ]
}
```

This is the correct GeoJSON format I have seen for leaflet consumption and use by MongoDb.. even for articles that use the Mongo shell to insert into Mongo then use via C#.  So something is amuck.

Comment: Looks like some of this may be due to legacy support as compared to the approved RFC. Coordinates requires lat, long; but the spec says 2 or more properties so _values_ would be allowed. Point vs 7 looks like it may be the  enum.int...

Comment: Thanks @MadMyche. I just checked the spec and it says 2 or more elements: ("A position is represented by an array of numbers. There must be at least two elements, and may be more.")

Comment: You're welcome, consider marking my comment as helpful if it truly was. I wish tools like these were around when I wrote GIS apps, mine was hand coded before Google Maps or MongoDB existed

Comment: I've done more digging. Turns out the issue is with the way the data is serialized by webapi/ASP.Net Core.  When I insert a document into mongo it looks fine - it's just when a webapi Get method returns a GeoJson object in the .Net MongoDb.Driver  eg GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>

Comment: You could create a  new class as a translator, using just lat/long/type etc and serialize that one

Comment: Here could be the solution to your problem [mongo_c#_geojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60806942/c-sharp-mongodb-geojsonpoint-json-object)