# C# MongoDB GeoJsonPoint JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-core, geolocation

I am having an issue of how to structure my geolocation object in my ASP.NET Core 3 application using the mongodb.driver

My object

```
public class Person
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; }
}
```

I am just doing a straight insertone and passing the object.  If I leave out the location it inserts find.

Here is the JSON object I am trying to pass to the api in a simple post.

```
{
"firstName": "Paul",
"lastName": "Staley",
"email": "someemail@nowhere.com",
"address": "12345 E 1st Ave",
"state": "AA",
"zipCode": "11111",
"phoneNumber": "555-555-5555",
"location":  {

    "coordinates": [
        0.123321,
        0.3453455
    ]
}

}
```

The error I get.

System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'MongoDB.Driver.GeoJsonObjectModel.GeoJsonPoint`1[MongoDB.Driver.GeoJsonObjectModel.GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates]'

Comment: Follow this example  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/nosql-database-persistence-infrastructure#a-model-used-by-mongodb-api

Comment: It looks like "location" was not properly constructed in the JSON string. You can check the proper formatting by serializing the result of something like this: `var location = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(32.0, 91.0));` :: this will show you what is expected.

Comment: Nkosi  The example you put up was the easiest way.  Thank you.  The object it wanted in json was large and convoluted and couldn't get it right.  The private set was easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer helped by Nksoi

Person Object

```
 public class Person
 {
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location
    { get; private set; }
    public void SetLocation(double lon, double lat) => SetPosition(lon, lat);


    private void SetPosition(double lon, double lat)
    {
        Latitude = lat;
        Longitude = lon;
        Location = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(
            new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(lon, lat));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreatePerson(Person person)
    {
        person.SetLocation(person.Longitude, person.Latitude);
        _personRepository.CreatePerson(person);

        return Ok();
    }
```

JSON Object

```
 "firstName": "Paul",
 "lastName": "Staley",
 "email": "someemail@nowhere.com",
 "address": "12345 E 1st Ave",
 "state": "AA",
 "zipCode": "11111",
 "phoneNumber": "555-555-5555",
 "latitude": 32.0,
 "longitude": 91.0
```